# creating perspective objects with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, client-side, perspective

How is it possible to create for example an object with perspective.

For example: http://www.spaceslide.co.uk/design-your-own.php?stage=5

In step 5 you can see the sliding wardrobe. If you want, you can also see the side (left or right). I think this is created with JQuery. My question is, how is this possible to create perspective and fill it with an image?

Or do you have any better ideas for creating perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't make anything slide, but I could see a perspective view of the side of the wardrobe.

The background image is overlaid with two  semi-transparent gifs obscuring part of the image.

Here's one of the gifs:

http://www.spaceslide.co.uk/static/images/configurator/masks/endpanel-top-left.gif

And the other:

http://www.spaceslide.co.uk/static/images/configurator/masks/endpanel-bottom-left.gif

Answer (score 1):

You can explore more on the stage 5, They have used [slidejs](http://slidesjs.com/) java script library, which provide this functionality.

To color the doors, They have used [panzoom.js](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/pan-zoom) library.  Example of coloring the part of page is given [here](http://www.cyberz.org/blog/2009/12/08/svgpan-a-javascript-svg-panzoomdrag-library/).

Comment: It must be compatible with IE 7 & 8. This is html 5 what you gave me there